# C# bot doesn't connect to voice channels (Discord.Net)

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

As described in the title, i can't seem to get my bot to join a voice channel in my discord.
The code for the command:

```
_commands.CreateCommand("join")
                .Description("Makes the bot join the first or default voice channel.")
                .Do(async (e) =>
                {
                    await e.Channel.SendIsTyping();
                    var voiceChannel = _client.FindServers("mealroom V2").FirstOrDefault().VoiceChannels.FirstOrDefault(); // Finds the first VoiceChannel on the server 'Music Bot Server'

                    var _vClient = await _client.GetService<AudioService>() // We use GetService to find the AudioService that we installed earlier. In previous versions, this was equivelent to _client.Audio()
                            .Join(VoiceChannel); // Join the Voice Channel, and return the IAudioClient.
                });
```

I'm using discord.Net 0.9.6.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

P.S i have the Iaudio code:

```
        _client.UsingAudio(x =>
        {
            x.Mode = AudioMode.Outgoing;
        });
```

Comment: Did you get an error? Have you tried putting your code in a try catch clause to see if you get an exception for further details?

Comment: no error, the bot runs perfectly fine it just doesn't connect to a vc.
I'll try what you said

Comment: I tried to do a try catch clause but i'm quite new to C# and very tired, i couldn't get it to work. The end bracket for try{ always connected to class MyBot {

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Comment: async error handling isn't very intuitive http://www.bartread.com/2014/02/13/c-quick-tip-does-exception-handling-work-with-async-method-calls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because writing code doesn't look very nice as a comment and your trouble with try catch:

```
try
{
    //your code here
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    //error handling or breakpoint to check the exception
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. If it's working I would be happy about an upvote ;)

Comment: @CaramelPanda you don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer, but thank the answerer by accepting the answer by clicking on the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the latest libsodium.dll and opus.dll for the bot to join the channel, otherwise the bot will not connect to the voice channel. I have a command that's not different at all to yours, and it works fine, if I were to remove those two, or possibly having them outdated, the bot will not join.